# Why a given user can access a folder and another one does not?

Tags: permissions, users, directory

I have two servers:

Server one:

```
deploy@server:/home/vftp$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 ftp  ftp  4096 May  7  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul 19  2013 ..
dr-xr-xr-- 3 ftp  ftp  4096 Feb 18  2013 ald

deploy@server:/home/vftp$ cd ald
deploy@server:/home/vftp/ald$
```

Server two:

```
deploy@server:/home/vftp$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 ftp  ftp  4096 Mar 17 11:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Mar 17 12:44 ..
dr-xr-xr-- 3 ftp  ftp  4096 Mar 17 11:01 ald

deploy@server:/home/vftp$ cd ald
bash: cd: ald: Permission denied
```

I can't understand anything about this behaviour. I need the deploy user in the "server two" to access the `ald` folder.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to directory is controlled by the execute attribute (x).

Your ald directory has permission to execute only to user/group so user deploy on server1 is probably a member of the group ftp, while on server 2 he isn't.

Either change the group membership of deploy on server2

```
useradd -G ftp deploy
```

or add others execute permission to ald directory

```
chmod o+x ald
```

Comment: Cool, thank you so much!! :) I was missing the obvious!

Comment: In addition, it is required to reload the user session :).